# For two objects X and Y in a category, with Y dominating X, prove that X dominates a Zero Object in our category.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

If we have a category, $C$, and two objects $X$ and $Y$ , and $Y$ dominates $X$.

I think with definition there is morphisms $f : X → Y$ and $g : Y → X$ in our category such that $g ◦ f = Id_X$. I want to show if a zero object exists in $C$, then objects $X$ will also dominate our zero object. And that our zero object can only dominate $X$ in $C$ if the zero object is a homeomorphism of $X$.

I know that our category has zero morphisms by the composition $0_{XY} : X → 0 → Y$ but I want to prove dominance.

Comment: What does it mean for one object to dominate another? I’m not familiar with this terminology.

Answer (score 0):

By uniqueness, the composition $0\to X\to 0$ is the identity on $0$, hence $X$ dominates $0$.

Comment: @confusedagain $0$ dominates $X$ iff the identity of $X$ is the zero morphism.

Comment: @confusedagain If the identity of $X$ is the zero morphism, then all morphisms $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to X$ are zero morphisms. Hence $X$ is a zero object.